# What does Material Design mean by 'action'?

Tags: interface-design, google-material-design, style-guide

For context, I'm a web developer implementing a project using [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/) a React framework that implements Google's Material Design.

One of the difficulties I'm having with the Material UI API documentation is that it doesn't provide much context for the purpose of it's various contexts.

For example - the [CardActionArea component](https://material-ui.com/api/card-action-area/) just says

> The API documentation of the CardActionArea React component.

So I've been going back to the source to understand what we mean by 'Card Action Area' (and how this differs from '[CardActions](https://material-ui.com/api/card-actions/)').

So the [original Material documentation for Cards](https://material.io/design/components/cards.html) goes into a bit more detail:

> Cards are surfaces that display content and actions on a single topic...
>
> **Actions**
>
> **Primary action**
>
> The primary action area of a card is typically the card itself. Often cards are one large touch target to a detail screen on a subject.

Oh god, I've solved it. This question feels too well written to discard it now.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept the answer after... some hours. If a question doesn't have an accepted answer, it gets automatically bumped to the front page every now and then.

Comment: ^Yup -I'll come back to it.

Comment: @dwjohnston it's been over a year, _are_ you going to come back to it?